# Zero padding in model, view or controller?

Tags: model-view-controller

There's some disagreement in my circle about where to 0-pad a number: model, view or controller. Since the number is stored as a number in the database, it has to be padded when necessary for display.

Opinions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do more with preference than protocol, but I feel that this should occur in the model.  This way your controller receives nice, clean data and doesn't need to modify the data at all.  I'm sure that there are some who would say that the controller should handle it because the model is strictly for database methods, but I don't think I agree with that.

I think we can all agree that this certainly shouldn't occur in the view...

Comment: Very arguable. I vote for view since it is a display preference only. One may want to have two views — one with padded number and another one with non-padded. In that case you will have to change the model, which sounds definitely fishy.

Comment: In my mind, the view should be clean from any sort of data processing.  I would structure my model in a manner that allows a different number of digits to be returned depending on the parameter passed to it from the controller.

Comment: It's true that at some point somebody might want the number without zeros. So making the model handle that seems strange since that would require two different methods or a flag passed to the one method or something. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Like I said, this is just my preference.  I would definitely pass the number of digits required in as a preference.  This question is pretty subjective ;)

Comment: @ViktorKilo: 
Indeed. I don't think there's a 'right' answer, so I was hoping to see what the community thought.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would also venture that the padding belongs in the model, more specifically - the View Model. Its true that models are useful for transferring data from the db. It also makes sense to use View Models to transport data from the controller to the view, keeping the view itself 'dumb' and the model unit testable. This is true at least in asp.net's simplified form of MVC.

Comment: Interesting. Our environment is php/Zend_Framework. I suppose view helpers could fill the roll your talking about. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are implementing either classical MVC, MVP or Model2 MVC pattern, it should be done in the View. Near the part whre you request data from the Model layer.
- If you actually us MVVM pattern, then either in View or ViewModel (the MVVM pattern is for situations, when you don't have full control over both model layer and view and you need to create an adapter between them).
- If you are using some Rails clone, that uses term "MVC" for marketing purposes, the formating should be in something they call "view helper".

> <sub>Silly people from ASP.NET MVC tend to call it "ViewModel" because they already decide to use name "View" to refer to templates. And now, instead of fixing the naming convention one pattern, MS opted for messing up another pattern - MVVM. Good job MS. Great for job security as always.</sub>